# How to convert list intervals (in string format) to integers?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to convert a string-like interval (example: '1:10') to a useful integer interval (example: 1:10). The point is that my methods aren't working. I tried to refer to the string interval and it didn't work:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
string_interval = '0:4'
x[string_interval]
```

Desired output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I also tried to convert the string_interval to an integer with int() but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a string like command and the evaluate it.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
string_interval = '0:4'

x_str = f'x[{string_interval}]'

x_cmd = eval(x_str)

print(x_cmd) # it is still a list object`
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] #0:4 interval
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) instance:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> string_interval = '0:4'
>>> item = slice(*map(int, string_interval.split(":")))
>>> x[item]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> idx = string_interval.split(':')
>>> x[int(idx[0]):int(idx[1])+1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Add 1 to the ending index because slices in Python go up to, but don't include the value at the ending index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval): `print(eval('x[%s]' % string_interval)) #[1,2,3,4]`

Also note that you need `string_interval='0:5'` to get [1,2,3,4,5] as you're basically giving it a [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).